# How can I pass a large string to an iMessage Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, string, segue, imessage-extension

I am creating an iMessage extension that converts an image to ASCII art (~60,000 chars) and sends it as a scrollView. I currently have an if statement that seques to a different view controller if the message was opened within the transcript. I then tried to send the ASCII art string over through the URL, but the string is too long to send over a URL. Is there any way to receive a string in an iMessage bubble without using a URL?

Comment: I ran into that limitation as well. You could try to compress your string into data or you could add a server component to store the string, then you can pass just an object id for that server object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CloudKit or Firebase to store the string works. Upload the string to the respective service's public key-value database and then send the key of the entry as a property of the iMessage extension message.